# Selenium IDE Recording Open or Save File in Firefox Interface

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm trying to Record with Selenium IDE Click on Firefox dialog box for Opening or Saving some generated pdf file on my web form but it's not recording it. Can anyone help me? I google whole internet and stackoverflow but nothing.
If it's not posible to do this with Selenium IDE how is it posible to do with java or javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not endorse the tool that is mentioned in [this](http://qtp-help.blogspot.com/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html) webpage but it seems that first paragraph is an answer to your question

Comment: this is helpful indeed.
I am interested how is this possible to do in Java?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful then please mark it as an "Accepted Answer"